# Check for characters before and after a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a one positive regex which combines all 3 of the following:

```
-- ^(.*)\.abc\.(.*)$
-- ^(.*)\.abc$
-- ^abc\.(.*)$
```

such that the below cases do not apply to the regex:

```
-- 123abc
-- .abc123
-- 123abc.
```

and the following fgive the positive result:

```
--.abc
--.abc.
--abc.
```

*I know that the 3 conditions can be in ORed in a group. I am looking fr a better solutoin, probably using lookaheads.*

I tried using backreferencing : `/^.*([\.]*)abc\1.*$/` but then this is positive for negative cases as well.

Comment: Are the `--` part of the input? Or just a placeholder?

Comment: placeholders only

Comment: `"--.abc".match(/^.{2}([.](abc))+$/g)`

Comment: Is `abc` a valid match?

Comment: @anubhava: yes it is. Also i did not downvote your ans

Comment: Yes I know didn't down vote. Even question was downvoted for some some unknown reasons.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal What else should match and shouldn't match? Please add more sample positive and negative input test cases.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Anubhava's answer works with me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(.*([.;]))?abc((?=[.;])\2.*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CEaw1J/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.*([.;]))?`: start with anything followed by dot or semicolon (optional match). Note that we capture before `abc` in capture group #2
- `abc`: match `abc`
- `((?=[.;])\2.*)?`: End with same character we captured before `abc` and anything following (optional match). Lookahead assertion is used to make sure we don't match empty back-reference `\2`
- `$`: End

Comment: why are you using a non capturing group?

Comment: Unless you want to capture some text it is better to use non capturing group to save memory.

Comment: I want to capture the character (.) before abc and replicate that optionally in the end

Comment: Also, your regex does not work for : abc.xyz *ignore*

Comment: RIght! sorry ... that was when i was using the regex before this

Comment: Can you please help me with a capturing group which can then replicate the capture in the end?

Comment: sure I can help. What do you want to capture? Do you want all the text before and after `abc` including dots?

Comment: So here I have taken the example of (.), but i can have ; as well. So i want to capture whether it is . or ; and then check that in the end using backreferencing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160072/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bhumi-singhal).